# JavaScript&CSS: корректное отображение с полосой прокрутки и без

Tags: javascript, css, адаптивная-верстка

Делая адаптивную вёрстку, столкнулся с проблемой полосы прокрутки.

Вкратце о моём коде. Я узнаю ширину окна и с помощью `window.onload` и `window.onresize` выполняю код как при первой загрузке, так и при каждом изменении ширины окна.

```
var WindowWidth = $("html").width();
```

Далее, примерно так я выстраиваю вёрстку:

```
...
if (WindowWidth >= 320 && WindowWidth < 375) {<команды формирования вёрстки>}
else if (WindowWidth >= 375 && WindowWidth < 480) {<команды формирования вёрстки>}
...
```

Для каждого диапазона ширин экрана (фазы) есть соответствующие медиа-запросы CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 374px){
    ... стили для указанного диапазона ... 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    ... стили для указанного диапазона ...
}
```

Все диапазоны в сумме образуют непрерывный интервал ширин от 0 до бесконечности (что будет отображаться при "невозможной" ширине экрана, например, в 1px - это другой вопрос).

Если, например, с помощью соответствующего расширения для chrome убрать скроллбар, то всё будет работать на ура. А вот когда вертикальная полоса прокрутки активна, будут проблемы. Как только мы *немного* привысим максимальную ширину интервала, указанного в JavaScript, вся вёрстка развалится, и так до тех пор, пока ширина *без* полосы прокрутки не достигнет какой-либо `min-width` из указанных.

Вероятно, это проблему можно было бы решить, узнав в помощью JS ширину полосы прокрутки (а в каждом браузере они разные) и прибавив её к `min-width` каждой фазы, но ведь тогда нужно согласовать эти ширины с теми, что в медиа-запросах стилевого файла; едва ли это можно сделать в пару строк кода.

Потом, вероятно в JS можно брать не ширину `window`, а ширину`viewport`. Но, во-первых, как это сделать, чтобы работало вне зависимости от устройства (компьютер, смартфон и т. д.)? Во-вторых, а будут ли эти ширины согласованы с медиазапросами CSS? В третьих, будет ли работать указанный ниже "пусковой механизм"?

```
window.onload = function() {
     window.onresize = F;
     F();
 };
```

где F() - основная функция, которая выполняется как при первой загрузке страницы, так и при изменении ширины окна.

Итак, сформулирую вопрос: как исправить приведённый выше код так, чтобы вёрстка корректно отображалась на любых устройствах вне зависимости от того, есть скроллбар или нет? Необходимо сохранять согласование всех `min-widtn` и `max-width` в JS-файле и CSS-файле. Для этого можно использовать JSON, если его читает не только JS, но LESS (насчёт возможности последнего пока достоверных данных не нашел).

Comment: `как исправить...` - Так может следует избавится от js и оставить только медиа-запросы?

Comment: К сожалению, если убрать JS, то будет утрачена возможность менять вёрстку (html-разметку) в зависимости от ширины экрана и можно будет менять только стили. Это не всегда допустимо: например, если в мобильной версии сайта нужно будет переместить боковую панель, одними стилями Вы едва ли обойдётесь.

Comment: Как вариант задайте для body{overflow-y: scroll} и скроллбар будет всегда активен и прыгать ничего не будет

Comment: Может на resize проверять наличие какого-то аттрибута, который по media-query устанавливается?

Comment: Прошу прощения, к сожалению не понял, что Вы имеете ввиду. Вы можете привести конкретный пример (не важно, сработает он или нет)?