# Не работает плагин jQuery malihu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В одном из комментариев на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548151/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment701006_548151) мой вопрос мне было предложено использовать [скроллбар malihu](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html) (плагин для jQuery). Задать вопрос в комментариях на странице разработчика не удалось - там глючит сервер при отправке комментария.

Мне не удалось заставить работать этот плагин таким образом:

```
<head>
    ...

    <!--css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">

    <!--js-->
    <!--<script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        (function($){
            $(window).on("load",function(){ 
                $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
                    theme:"minimal"
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</head>
```

Все пути я проверил - всё нормально; соединение со всеми файлами есть. Скрипт перед закрывающим `</head>` тоже работает. Я посмотрел через браузер код HTML после рендеринга: новые элементы были добавлены. Тем не менее, браузер всё ещё показывает стандартный скроллбар. Я что-то упустил?

---

**Обновление**

Я проверил решение пользователя **Dmitry** на одном из своих проектов и оно сработало. Вот как выглядит работающий код: плагин присвоивает `<body>` свой класс, "запихивает" содержимое сайта, что было до рендеринга, в первый `<div>` и после него добавляет ещё один:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на другом моём сайте плагин сработал неверно. Как видно на рисунке ниже, класс `<body>` присвоен, а `<div>`ы не добавлены:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может дело? Я могу предположить такие варианты:

- У меня адаптивная вёрстка, и html-код формируется как при загрузке страницы (`onload`), так и при изменении ширины окна (`onresize`). Каждый раз происходит очистка содержимого, и добавление нового. Подробнее я описал свой код [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544645/javascriptcss-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7?noredirect=1#comment693436_544645) (не буду дублировать). Я постарался встроить скрипт сроллбара в свой код, но безрезультатно.
- А может быть дело в блоке `wrapper`, который также оборачивает всё содержимое сайта? Даже не могу сказать, почему я так предположил, потому что не знаю подробностей технической реализации скроллбара malihu.

Comment: "...браузер всё ещё показывает стандартный плагин" стандартный скролл, видимо. если новые элементы добавлены, то следует приложить скрин, думаю, чтобы понять, как оно не работает

Comment: Да не вопрос, скрин я  приложу, но едва ли с него будет какая-то информативность (ничего, кроме Ghrome-скроллбара, там нет, а на содержимое сайта никакого влияния нет, так что я его не включил в скрин).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, нужно прописать нужные css-правила:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: "minimal"
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="height: 2000px"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. В одном из моих сайтов Ваше решение сработало, но в другом - нет. Я добавил описание в вопрос.